# What are words like "excellent, good, great, perfect" called?

Tags: adjectives

Is there a specific term for these kinds of words that describe the quality of a particular act or object?  Besides adjective?

Examples:

- Perfect
- Excellent
- Great
- Good
- Bad
- Poor
- Terrible
- Horrible

Comment: You are looking for something that describes only positive attributes? If not, what is missing in _adjectives_?

Comment: @oerkelens Is there a specific name for these particular attributes?  The ones that describe a condition of something.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for *intensifier*? If so, I would caution you that not all adjectives are intensifiers.

Comment: Which particular attributes? Good ones, or do you also want to include "bad", "terrible", etc?

Comment: Three roles for the types of modification achieved using adjectives have been suggested: identifiers, classifiers and  descriptors. These above are most probably descriptive usages. They may be subdivided into adjectives describing size / weight / temperature / humidity / age / shape / color / materials ... These above ascribe _worth_ / _value_ to the referent, so they are **evaluative**.

Comment: They also look to me like *superlatives*. I am not speaking necessarily of grammatical *superlatives*, but those covered by OED meaning 1b (of *superlative*). *characterised by exaggeration, hyperbolical*.

Comment: So I'm confused, are these adjectives, are they identifiers? Are they intensifiers? Are they superlatives?

Comment: @WS2 Some of them are superlatives, but _good_ and _bad_ aren't very extreme.

Comment: No, none are superlatives.  Superlatives are used when comparing three or more things (e.g. "best", "worst", etc.).

Comment: @Bamar Well I'm looking to describe the words that convey the meaning of quality, so while good and bad may not be on the extremes of that scale, it still exists as a "quality" word

Comment: @Kevin They certainly are not the _grammatical_ superlative as you have identified; but they are indeed _characterized by exaggeration_, as WS2 pointed out, and so I think the term applies quite well. _Descriptive adjectives_ and _intensifying adjectives_ also seem to work well, in my opinion.

Comment: @blancocayo They are probably more than one of those things. What is there to stop an adjective being both an *intensifier* and a *superlative*, for example?

Comment: @Justin: IMHO that term is a bad idea in this context.  It's too easily confused with the grammatical sense, which (unlike the sense WS2 was using) is *exclusive to individual words*.  The more specific sense is the one most people will assume by context.

Comment: (1) They are **adjectives**. But then so are _small_, _smelly_, and _pink_. (2) They are usually used as **descriptors** (He's a good man / She is so good) but can be used eg as identifiers (He's taken the _good_ car, Mr Wayne). Like many adjectives. (3) They make a statement about the referent's worth, and so are **evaluative** adjectives. Unlike _small_, _smelly_, and _pink_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your question is about words that describe points along a scale of desirability, I would call them *ratings*.

Answer (score 4):

These are called "[superlatives](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/superlative)" in the positive sense.

In the negative sense, they could be considered "shades (or levels) of [mediocrities](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mediocrities)".

Comment: Grammatically  the word "superlative" is usually reserved for the most extreme of three adjectives formed from the same root (the midde one is called the " comparative").  So:  tall, taller (comparative), tallest (superlative).  Short,shorter,shortest. Some have non-standard forms: good, better, best; bad, worse, worst. So none of the OP's examples are superlatives.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: actually, _perfect_ is a superlative, albeit borrowed from Latin: bonus, melior, perfectus. That is why some people fuss over _more perfect_ and the likes.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I would fuss over " mote perfect" as well. Good Latin lesson. Now I know why  I couldn't think of the English adjective or its comparative for which "perfect" is the superlative. Super-ameliorated Bonus!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock You could even call it _perfectly ameliorated bonus_ and get all three terms in one go.

Answer (score -3):

How about calling them Superlatives.

Comment: Grammatically  the word "superlative" is usually reserved for the most extreme of three adjectives formed from the same root (the midde one is called the " comparative").  So:  tall, taller (comparative), tallest (superlative).  Short,shorter,shortest. Some have non-standard forms: good, better, best; bad, worse, worst. So none of the OP's examples are superlatives.